# Не работает метод submit();

Tags: javascript

Не работает этот метод(

```
<script>
function testID(id, type){
    document.getElementById('beforepay').submit();
}
</script>

<form accept-charset="windows-1251" target="_blank" id="beforepay" name="beforepay" method="post" action="" onSubmit="testID(322332, 1);return false;">
<input autocomplete="OFF" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);" name="submit" value="Далее" type="submit">
</form>
```

В консоли пишет:

> `document.getElementById("beforepay").submit is not a function`

В чём моя ошибка?
Причём, я заметил что не работает, когда submit в handleresponse

Comment: Может быть, у вас есть другой элемент с таким же ID? Например, кнопка. Проверьте.

Comment: Если бы так было то не работало бы всегда, а то так работает:<br>
<code>xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = document.getElementById("beforepay").submit();</code>
<br>А так нет:<br>
<code>xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
document.getElementById("beforepay").submit();
}</code><br>
Не могу понять по какой причине(

Comment: попробуй обратиться к форме как forms['beforepay'].submit();

Comment: Пишет <b>forms is not defined</b>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Здесь все намного проще - проблема в вашем коде, а именно в

```
<input autocomplete="OFF" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);" name="submit" value="Далее" type="submit">
```

Теперь поясню - в javascript'e расспарсиваются значения формы по атрибуту name, после это мы можем иметь к ним доступ. Т.е. в нашем случае - функция `document.beforepay.submit` перезаписывается значением вашего инпута, именно поэтому `submit is not a function`, потомучто в этом случае `submit` - это input...
Вообщем для решения это проблемы просто смените атрибут `name` для вашего инпута на что угодно только не на submit :)
Кстати чисто для себя - сделайте `alert(document.beforepay.submit)` и вы увидите что это html input

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. Я просто форму не сам писал, а копировал) Отсюда и бред типа autocomplete="OFF" на кнопке) name=submit не бросалась в глаза из-за многочисленности атрибутов) Благо дарю)
Но возникла проблема: когда отправка формы идёт через js то браузеры блокируют это как всплывающее окно, т.к. target=_blank. Можно как то этого избежать? Или убрать _blank только?

Comment: о возникла проблема:.... а где сама проблема то? ^^

Comment: Ясно, спасибо)